# when we call normal function in $q is this work as asynchronous or not?

Tags: angularjs

```
        *

// for the purpose of this example let's assume that variables `$q` and `okToGreet`
            // are available in the current lexical scope (they could have been injected or passed in).
          // perform some asynchronous operation, resolve or reject the promise when appropriate.


        function asyncGreet(name) {

          return $q(function(resolve, reject) { //function to call in $q
            setTimeout(function() {
              if (okToGreet(name)) {
                myFun()////call function in here which is not async
                resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');//call function in here
              } else {
                reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
              }

            }, 1000);
          });
        }

  // for the purpose of this example let's assume that variables `$q` and `okToGreet`
        // are available in the current lexical scope (they could have been injected or passed in).
      // perform some asynchronous operation, resolve or reject the promise when appropriate.
//function to call in $q
```

*

Comment: sorry for formatting .. i want to call normal function which is not asynchronous can $q make it asynchronous or not ..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$q** is used to manage asynchronous enviroment in javascript which is tipical in event programming. Callbacks in **$q** are also asynchronous it means it will call after current call stack ( in You example it will be setTimeout callback function as current call stack ). I prepared some example:

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("cont",function($q){

  function asyncGreet() {

  var deferred = $q.defer();  
     
  setTimeout(function(){
      
       console.log("-- Standard log 1");
       
       //example asnychronous call using setTimeout
       setTimeout(function(){ console.log("--- Call in timeout 2");});

       //our function is called as third
       deferred.resolve();

       console.log("-- Standard log 4");
       console.log("-- Standard log 5");
       
  },1000);
    
  return deferred.promise;  
    
  };  
            
            
  
  console.log("- asyncGreat call 0");

  asyncGreet().then(function(){
  
    console.log("--- Resolve log 3");
    
  });
  
  console.log("- after asyncGreat call 6");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="cont">
</div>
```

Resolve is called in middle but in console we see that is called last. Reason is asynchronous behavior of **$q**, callback is called after current call stack, so after all code in `setTimeout`.

The same situation is with call `setTimeout` without time, it will run asynchronous after current call stack.

I purposely set numbers in console logs, numbers are showing position of calls in code, but asynchronous of $q and timeouts shows that position in code and real calling them does not match.

And to the question, no - only resolve and reject will run asynchronous to the current call stack, standard function call will run in standard way, but in Your example we have setTimeout after 1sec, so more complex call stack like this:

```
- asyncGreat() call
-- async call of setTimeout callback after 1s
--- async call code in second setTimeout
--- async call code in resolve
```

Comment: Thank You!!!!  that's mean  if we call function in $q so it act as asynchronous...this scenario we understand by your help